# How to publish Unity Game Engine app (executable binary) to Ubuntu Store?

Tags: unity, application-development, games

Quite recently [Unity Game Engine](https://unity3d.com/) (not to be confused with Ubuntu's Unity user interface) added an option to create a linux build. The result is a set of two executable binary files .x86 and .x86-64, plus a folder with some resources. I have exported my Unity game and it runs great on my Ubuntu machine.

I would like to publish the game on the Ubuntu Store, but I have no idea how to do it, and if it is possible at all. The [Ubuntu store tutorial](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/) instructs me to use Ubuntu SDK for packaging into "click app". When I run the SDK, it asks me what kind of project I want to create, with lots of project type options (QML App, HTML5 App, Web App, Plain C Application made with gmake etc), but I cannot see any way to simply package the existing executable binaries exported from Unity.

Could anyone help? My game (don't want to advertise here) would be a great and free asset in the Ubuntu store, to the benefit of the whole community :)

To clarify: I don't want to publish sources of my app; and of course I am not able to publish any sources of Unity Engine player. I simply want to publish my free app to the store, which I have as binary.

Comment: If you already have binary files, see https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/commercial-apps-packaging-setup/, http://askubuntu.com/a/27731/158442 - this will create a bunch of files - some with with `.orig.tar.gz`, `.dsc` extensions. You need to submit these files (see https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/my-apps-packages/). Even though your code might be open source, it has to be built using the Unity engine, so it can't be published the other way.

Comment: As far as I know, Ubuntu apps [should be written in QML or HTML5](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/) and they should run both on Desktop and mobiles. I do not think that Unity Game engine works on Ubuntu touch and/or it is easily packageable in a click package. As also pointed out by @muru you might have huge licensing problems if you are redistributing the engine.

Comment: From what I have read and understood so far, the only way to package binary is to make a .deb file (which seems to be quite complex by the way, and no examples for closed-source projects are available, yet people claim it is possible), and the only way to push .deb into Ubuntu Store is through debian repositories. However, debian does not accept closed source projects. If this is true, then the answer is: no, it is not possible to publish Unity apps to the Ubuntu store (which may explain why I could not find any, while all the other platforms are flooded with 3d games). Am I correct?

Comment: @pryma no, you don't have to go through Debian to get through to Ubuntu.  See the third link in my previous comment

Comment: Look at [Installing a program on a ubuntu touch phone](http://askubuntu.com/a/614300/391744) question. There is a CMake file that generates Click package for Ubuntu-Touch. You can change it to package any binary. Also it's possible to use the command-line Click packager tool directly.

Answer (score 0):

No you can use snaps. And it would let you to package for all distributions

https://dashboard.snapcraft.io/register-snap/

Here you first need to put your Unity packaged linux game on github you can make it private or public thats up to you you have tick the box while registering here which says "Is it a private package". then submit your package it will automaticaly be converted to snap package and after some days ubuntu will put it on software centre.

Comment: 'it will automaticaly be converted to snap package' source for this? I thought snaps had to be made with `snapcraft.yaml` files as per [the tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-your-first-snap#0)?

Comment: when you create games using Unity and package it for linux it gives a file extension where you dont have to use travis way as described here https://docs.snapcraft.io/build-snaps/ci-integration  instead of the travis method that you are saying, you should use the launchpad method that you have to follow.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the "Using Launchpad" method in the above snap craft document link. :)